# How to clear or remove plotly graph and datatable in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, shinydashboard

please share the function or default methods to  clear or remove the plotly graph and Data table once logout button is clicked.

When i click the logout button particular function like clearUI<- function() will be called which contains below code

```
 output$sumofissue = renderPlotly({NULL})
 output$averageeffort =renderPlotly({NULL})
 output$averageissue= renderPlotly({NULL})
 output$Datatable =DT::renderDataTable({NULL})
```

once this method is implemented . it is not triggering event reactive function rather than it is failed to  load the graph and datatable again for the same user

Instead  of passing NULL value . is there any way to clear the output of graph and data table in R shiny ?

Answer (score 0):

Empty plotly graph can be rendered with the following code:

```
renderPlotly({
  plotly_empty()
})
```

And completely non-interactive empty plotly graph can be rendered like the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
renderPlotly({
  plotly_empty() %>% 
  config(staticPlot = TRUE)
})
```

I think the second one is preferred almost all situations.